# Как получить стандартные иконки файловой системы из приложения под iOS?

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Хочу написать что-то типа файлового браузера для iOS - нужны стандартные иконки файловой системы (открытая папка, закрытая папка, файл, и т.д.). Как мне их вставить в UIImage или использовать каким-либо другим образом в своем приложении? Под стандартными имею ввиду изображения из System/Library/CoreServices/...

Comment: Их вроде никак нельзя получить...

Comment: Можно - надо разлочить ФС девайса. А вот как это сделать... например, это точно производится при JailBreak.

Comment: что вроде такой[link text][1]


  [1]: http://origin.arstechnica.com/reviews/os/mac-os-x-10-5.media/leopard-folder.png???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Что вроде такой

По моему в iOS нету стандартных ресурсов папок.
Особено указаного по ссылке. Но зато они есть OSX:

```
[NSImage imageNamed:@"NSFolder"]
```

Ты можешь выдрать их через проект Cocoa под OSX и импортировать их уже в свой iOS проект.

Только не знаю как руководство apple будет к этому относиться

---

Полный список системных `image'ов:

```
    NSQuickLookTemplate,
    NSBluetoothTemplate,
    NSIChatTheaterTemplate,
    NSSlideshowTemplate,
    NSActionTemplate,
    NSSmartBadgeTemplate,
    NSPathTemplate,
    NSInvalidDataFreestandingTemplate,
    NSLockLockedTemplate,
    NSLockUnlockedTemplate,
    NSGoRightTemplate,
    NSGoLeftTemplate,
    NSRightFacingTriangleTemplate,
    NSLeftFacingTriangleTemplate,
    NSAddTemplate,
    NSRemoveTemplate,
    NSRevealFreestandingTemplate,
    NSFollowLinkFreestandingTemplate,
    NSEnterFullScreenTemplate,
    NSExitFullScreenTemplate,
    NSStopProgressTemplate,
    NSStopProgressFreestandingTemplate,
    NSRefreshTemplate,
    NSRefreshFreestandingTemplate,
    NSFolder,
    NSTrashEmpty,
    NSTrashFull,
    NSHomeTemplate,
    NSBookmarksTemplate,
    NSCaution,
    NSStatusAvailable,
    NSStatusPartiallyAvailable,
    NSStatusUnavailable,
    NSStatusNone,
    NSApplicationIcon,
    NSMenuOnStateTemplate,
    NSMenuMixedStateTemplate,
    NSUserGuest,
    NSMobileMe,
    NSMultipleDocuments,
    NSUser,
    NSUserGroup,
    NSEveryone,
    NSBonjour,
    NSDotMac,
    NSComputer,
    NSFolderBurnable,
    NSFolderSmart,
    NSNetwork,
    NSUserAccounts,
    NSPreferencesGeneral,
    NSAdvanced,
    NSInfo,
    NSFontPanel,
    NSColorPanel,
    NSIconViewTemplate,
    NSListViewTemplate,
    NSColumnViewTemplate,
    NSFlowViewTemplate;
```